# TeamCity configuration in Kotlin - build id conflict in subprojects

Tags: kotlin, teamcity

Can build Id be generated based on subproject Id
rather then root project id ?

I'm getting validation error:

```
BuildType 'RootProjectId_build': id 'RootProjectId_build' is already used
in BuildType(uuid='', id='RootProjectId_build', name='buildA')
```

for the following project with 2 subprojects and builds that have the same class name (but in different packages)

RootTestProject.kt

```
package _Self

import A.SubProjectA
import B.SubProjectB
import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.v2018_1.Project

object RootTestProject : Project({
    subProject(SubProjectA)
    subProject(SubProjectB)
})
```

SubProjectA.kt :

```
package A

import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.v2018_1.BuildType
import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.v2018_1.Project

object build : BuildType({name = "buildA"})

object SubProjectA : Project({
    name = "SubProjectNameA"
    buildType(build)
})
```

SubProjectB.kt :

```
package B

import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.v2018_1.BuildType
import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.v2018_1.Project

object build : BuildType({name = "buildB"})

object SubProjectB : Project({
    name = "SubProjectNameB"
    buildType(build)
})
```

For some reason I need to stay with same class names for builds, so I won't simply change 'object build' to 'object buildA' and 'object buildB'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming package name is equivalent to subproject
the workaround is:

```
object build : BuildType({name = "buildB"
    id(this.javaClass.`package`.name +"_"+id.toString().split("_")[1])
})
```

this way build Id is: `RootProjectId_B_build`